# bootstrap 3 grid layout not working in IE8

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I've been trying to get the grid layout system of Bootstrap 3 to work well with IE8, but it just doesn't work. I do not have any need for a responsive layout.

To be absolutely sure that I'm not introducing some random errors in the HTML file I've created, I went ahead and downloaded a fresh copy of Bootstrap 3. After extracting the contents, I opened the example grid HTML file (within the /examples/grid folder), and lo behold, even in the official distribution, the *grids appear stacked on top of each other*, instead of spanning across a row!

What's strange though, when I browse to the [inline forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal) section of the online documentation on my IE8, the grid layout seems to work just fine.

Comment: Have you included respond.js? It's required for media queries to work in IE 8.

Comment: @Pavlo `respond.js` is included by default in the official distribution example files.

Comment: Indeed. Maybe there are some errors in the browser console? Try to type `respond` to see if it was linked correctly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem it appears is using the wrong class for the grids. Even though the screen size of my Windows system was larger than my Mac book's, I made the wrong assumption that the resolution would be the same or higher.

I had developed my site on the mac, and used `.col-md-` classes for the grid layout. However, since the resolution of my Win device was lower, `.col-xs-` should have been used. And hence, it was appearing stacked.

Lesson: Even though your Win system might have a larger screen, it's resolution can be as low as that of a tablet.

Comment: This is not a solution, in my case I want the xs to be stacked and the large to be floating left so I have a col-md-3 and col-xs-12. The problem in IE8 is that with a full screen it shows col-md-3 stacked when Chrome or Firefox shows a 3 column layer (which is what is wanted).

Comment: for div#row it's working .but for pull-left or pull-right in container seems it  lose margin and padding ....

Answer (score 14):

According to the [Bootstrap 3 docs](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#browsers) you need to include [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond#respondjs) in order to get the CSS 3 media queries to work. Hope that helps!

Comment: actually, `respond.js` is included by default. the problem, as i mentioned, was to do with the wrong class.

Comment: I selectively include what I use from Bootstrap, so this was precisely what I needed.